# Trying to post an array with `pg`, but keep getting wrong type error - Postgres, Express, Node

Tags: arrays, postgresql, express

I have a route in my `express` app that takes an array and I am trying to update my db with the array.  Here is my route:

```
exports.postUser = function(req, res) {
  var query = client.query('insert into user_subservices(user_id, subservice_id) select $1 id, x from unnest(ARRAY[$2]) x', [req.body.id, req.body.services]);
  query.on('row', function(row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
  });
  query.on('end', function(result) {
    res.json(result);
  });
} ;
```

I am trying to do a query where I add each element in the array individually like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_subservices(user_id, subservice_id) 
SELECT 1 id, x
FROM    unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,22,33]) x;
```

But I keep getting an error that says that my type is wrong:

```
Error: column "subservice_id" is of type integer but expression is of type text
```

I assumed my `body` coming in on my REST call was text, so then I tried to convert the array with this:

```
var intArray = _.map(req.body.services, function(a) {
  return parseInt(a);
});
```

But I still got the same error that it was of type text.  What else do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I got a different error. `Error: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"`

Comment: I was able to make the query work, but it is just a hack until I can find out what really needs to happen.  Here is the code that I am using.  `var queryText2 = "insert into user_subservices(user_id, subservice_id) select " + 2 + ' id, x from unnest(ARRAY[' + req.body.services +']) x';
  var query2 = client.query(queryText2);`  I create the query myself, instead of letting the framework do it. Maybe this will help get closer to a correct answer.